# Using PyPy Sandbox to refer to standard python modules?

Tags: python, sandbox, interpreter, pypy

I am currently working on a project to embed a Python interpreter in my website--I would like users to be able to execute their own Python code on the server-side in a secure Python sandbox. I have been using PyPy's sandboxing features and have set my virtual tmp/ directory (which corresponds to the real directory that the sandbox can read from) to my server-side files. So ideally, users will be able to run their own code on the server and use whatever libraries I make available to them (with no ability to write to any of these files/make system calls/do anything in general that would mess up my files).

The issue is that within my server-side code I use standard Python libraries as well as others I have installed separately (e.g. "import datetime", "import pandas", etc.). While the sandbox can read my server-side code it ends up failing whenever I try to import additional libraries within this code. I have thought of setting my virtual tmp/ directory to include my server-side files + the standard Python libraries + separately installed libraries such as PANDAS. However, when I tried setting it to just the Python libraries it ended up not working, not to mention that this solution seems pretty inelegant.

Any thoughts on how to go about fixing this? I appreciate whatever advice anyone may have. Thanks!

EDIT: I think part of the answer lies in the following portion of pypy_interact.py (the full source code can be found here: https://github.com/ojii/sandlib/blob/master/sandlib/pypy_interact.py):

```
 def build_virtual_root(self):
    # build a virtual file system:
    # * can access its own executable
    # * can access the pure Python libraries
    # * can access the temporary usession directory as /tmp
    exclude = ['.pyc', '.pyo']
    if self.tmpdir is None:
        tmpdirnode = Dir({})
    else:
        tmpdirnode = RealDir(self.tmpdir, exclude=exclude)
    libroot = str(LIB_ROOT)

    return Dir({
        'bin': Dir({
            'pypy-c': RealFile(self.executable),
            'lib-python': RealDir(os.path.join(libroot, 'lib-python'),
                                  exclude=exclude), 
            'lib_pypy': RealDir(os.path.join(libroot, 'lib_pypy'),
                                  exclude=exclude),
            }),
         'tmp': tmpdirnode,
         })
```

I am relatively new to Python and can't seem to figure out how to use this method properly. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.